Can I read solana(lamport) balance changes from simulateTransaction result?
get lamport balance changes from simulateTransaction result
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "context": {
            "apiVersion": "1.18.12",
            "slot": 297455041
        },
        "value": {
            "accounts": [{
                "data": ["", "base64"],
                "executable": false,
                "lamports": 2197082320,
                "owner": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
                "rentEpoch": 18446744073709551615,
                "space": 0
            }, {
                "data": ["", "base64"],
                "executable": false,
                "lamports": 2995049198,
                "owner": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
                "rentEpoch": 18446744073709551615,
                "space": 0
            }, {
                "data": ["c3lzdGVtX3Byb2dyYW0=", "base64"],
                "executable": true,
                "lamports": 1,
                "owner": "NativeLoader1111111111111111111111111111111",
                "rentEpoch": 18446744073709551615,
                "space": 14
            }],
            "err": null,
            "innerInstructions": null,
            "logs": ["Program 6kyAE2eHjdiupYVp9Qs6pjbq8Frk7G5deLAaW8tEtEBu invoke [1]", "Program log: Instruction: TransferLamports", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program 6kyAE2eHjdiupYVp9Qs6pjbq8Frk7G5deLAaW8tEtEBu consumed 3196 of 200000 compute units", "Program 6kyAE2eHjdiupYVp9Qs6pjbq8Frk7G5deLAaW8tEtEBu success"],
            "returnData": null,
            "unitsConsumed": 3196
        }
    },
    "id": 1
}


On its own, simulateTransaction doesn't give you changes to the accounts, just the new state of the accounts, so you'll need to fetch the accounts separately and compare the output.

thank you..that fixes it
